# Vue - non parent child communication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, emit

When reading Vue document
[Non parent-child communication](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication)
For practice, I tried to build an example to see if it works, below is my code:
I build two component and tried to use Vue instance bus to transport message from dudi-station to dudo-station while on-click, but it's not working.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

```js
Vue.component('dudi-station', {
  template: '<div @click="sentMsg">{{dudiMsg}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      dudiMsg: 'Dudi!!',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sentMsg: function() {
      bus.$emit('callout', this.dudiMsg);
    },
  }
});

Vue.component('dudo-station', {
  template: '<div>{{dudoMsg}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      dudoMsg:'',
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    bus.$on('callout', function(value) {
      this.dudoMsg = value;
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
});

var bus = new Vue();
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dudi-station></dudi-station>
  <dudo-station></dudo-station>
</div>
```

Comment: Sad, I still can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this statement:

```
bus.$on('callout', function(value) {
  this.dudoMsg = value;
```

this ***this*** is not mean your vue instance.
You need to use arrow function to make sure that 'this' means the vue instance.
Like below:

```js
Vue.component('dudi-station', {
  template: '<div @click="sentMsg">{{dudiMsg}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      dudiMsg: 'Dudi!!',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sentMsg: function() {
      bus.$emit('callout', this.dudiMsg);
    },
  }
});

Vue.component('dudo-station', {
  template: '<div>{{dudoMsg}}</div>',
  data: function() {
    return {
      dudoMsg:'',
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    bus.$on('callout',value => {
      this.dudoMsg = value;
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
});

var bus = new Vue();
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dudi-station></dudi-station>
  <dudo-station></dudo-station>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function as event handler when receiving message in component from another component. It will help you with "this" keyword scope.

```
bus.$on('callout', function(value) {
  this.dudoMsg = value;
  console.log(value);
});
```

instead of this use it as below

```
bus.$on('callout', (value) => {
  this.dudoMsg = value;
  console.log(value);
});
```